# Fullcalendar update only last event with eventDrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I recently implemented Fullcalendar v4.2.0 to my Laravel 7 project.

I'm currently trying to use the eventDrop function which helps to update data when an event is dragged-dropped somewhere else on the calendar.

When I move the event, it is updated as expected with an ajax request. After that, I tried to add a bootstrap modal to confirm the modifications before executing the request. If the user doesn't accept, the event is put back to its original place with a "event.revert".

Then I realised that those events that I move are being "linked" together.

**Example 1 :**

- **step 1 :** I move an event from A to B and I accept the modification, the request is made and it gets updated. The event has a new location on the calendar.
- **step 2 :** Then, I move another event from C to D and also accept, the request is made and it gets updated. The event has a new location on the calendar.

But when I look in the console, I see that when I move the second event, the first one is also being updated. Of course, I don't want that and I'd prefer to only update the last event I moved.

**Example 2 :**

- **step 1 :** I move an event from A to B and I accept the modification, the request is made and it gets updated. The event has a new location on the calendar.
- **step 2 :** Then, I move another event from C to D and I **cancel**. I call the event.revert() function and the event goes back to its previous place **BUT** the event I moved before on step 1 also goes back to its previous place, as before I updated it. If I refresh the page, that event goes back to its correct place, fetched from the database.

Here's the code I use for **eventDrop**

```
eventDrop(event) {
    $('#modalUpdateDate').modal();
        $(document).on('click', "#button_confirm_drop", function () {
            let id = event.event._def.extendedProps.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/rdvs/" + id,
                    data: {
                        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        date_debut_rdv: moment(event.event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
                        date_fin_rdv: moment(event.event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        console.log(event);
                        $('#modalUpdateDate').modal('hide');
                    }
                })
            });
        $(document).on('click', "#button_cancel_drop", function () {
            event.revert();
            $('#modalUpdateDate').modal('hide');
        });
}
```

The **modal**

```
<div id="modalUpdateDate" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h5>Confirm the update ?</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="button_cancel_drop" id="button_cancel_drop">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" name="button_confirm_drop" id="button_confirm_drop">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I see with console.log(event) after the ajax request is successfully done with **Example 1** :

**step 1**

```
Object { el: a.fc-time-grid-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.fc-draggable, delta: {…}, oldEvent: {…}, event: {…}, revert: revert(), jsEvent: mouseup, view: {…} }
```

**step 2**

```
Object { el: a.fc-time-grid-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.fc-draggable, delta: {…}, oldEvent: {…}, event: {…}, revert: revert(), jsEvent: mouseup, view: {…} }
Object { el: a.fc-time-grid-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.fc-draggable, delta: {…}, oldEvent: {…}, event: {…}, revert: revert(), jsEvent: mouseup, view: {…} }
Object { el: a.fc-time-grid-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.fc-draggable, delta: {…}, oldEvent: {…}, event: {…}, revert: revert(), jsEvent: mouseup, view: {…} }
```

With the first line coming from step 1

So I'm trying to see how I could update only the last event I move ? I tried to search but I couldn't find much as some solutions were related older version of Fullcalendar.

A little help would be very appreciated !
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$(document).on('click', "#button_confirm_drop"` gets executed every time `eventDrop` runs. This just adds more and more event  handlers to that button each time an event is dropped. It doesn't remove the previous handlers. So every time you click the button, it will run _all_ the event handlers attached to it. In other words, the callback runs multiple times, and it remembers the values it had from the previous runs, and repeats them. That's why you see your previous events being moved. Same for `$(document).on('click', "#button_cancel_drop"`.

Comment: I suggest using `.off()` (https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove earlier event handlers before attaching new ones.

Comment: P.S. None of this problem really has anything to do with fullCalendar, it's all related to DOM events and jQuery

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Yes indeed it is about DOM and jquery. I'm still trying to understand this better.

So I added the `.off()` function like so after updating or reverting with `event.revert()` :

    `$(document).off("click", "#button_confirm_drop");`

    `$(document).off("click", "#button_cancel_drop");`

It is indeed working but is this the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Pretty much yes.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your help !